# Include auto increment field to JSON response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

New to Django and Django Rest.

I am looking to modify the JSON return response of my view so that it also returns the id of the created user.

The things is, the id is an auto increment integer and so I don't know how I can retrieve the info to add it to the JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**models.py**

```
class CustomUsers(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        db_table = "custom_users"
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CustomUsersCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        last_name = validated_data['last_name']
        first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        username = validated_data['username']
        email = validated_data['email']
        password = validated_data['password']
        user_obj = USER(
            last_name=last_name,
            first_name=first_name,
            username=username,
            email=email,
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        return validated_data
    class Meta:
        model = USER
        fields = ('id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'username', 'password', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 10}}
```

**views.py**

```
class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomUsersCreateSerializer
    queryset = CustomUsers.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `Model.objects.create()` to add new record but i think it's the same as your way of using save() so you can get created user id after save:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    last_name = validated_data['last_name']
    first_name = validated_data['first_name']
    username = validated_data['username']
    email = validated_data['email']
    password = validated_data['password']
    user_obj = User.objects.create(
        last_name=last_name,
        first_name=first_name,
        username=username,
        email=email,
    )
    user_obj.set_password(password)
    user_obj.save()
    validated_data['user_id'] = user_obj.id
    return validated_data
```